# Creación de ecuaciones en CaseWare IDEA

Tags: base-de-datos

Tengo una BD anexada en CaseWare IDEA. De los distintos campos que tiene, en la ecuación que quiero crear influyen 2; "MATERIAL" y "CTD_EN_UM_ENTRADA". Quiero crear un nuevo campo, "UNIDADES_AGREGADAS". Dicho campo quiero que me calcule la acumulación de las cantidades de "CTD_EN_UM_ENTRADA", pero la acumulación quiero que me la realice de los posibles valores que puede asumir mi otro campo "MATERIAL". La versión que tengo es la 10.2.1.56 (X86).
GRACIAS!